# Is 'that is' optional?

Tags: abbreviations

When I write something like this:

> I am a man that is doing these things.

Is it correct to shorten it like this?

> I am a man doing these things.

And does it require commas?

Comment: In your first sentence, *who is* would sound better than *that is*. I don't know why; you can grammatically use *that* to refer to people.

Comment: Reserving "who" as a definite article for people is a convention followed by careful writers. Definitely a matter of usage - oft observed in the breach.

Comment: Both are grammatical, and neither requires commas, but both are unlikely sentences. It's almost impossible to comment further without knowing the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'**Who** is doing these things?'
'**I am** the man who is doing these things'

'Who is doing **these** things?'
'I am the man doing **these** things'

Depending on the context, we can omit the '*that is*'/'*who is*'. Sometimes this will help to shift the focus/emphasis in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatical sentences, but the first one sounds a bit awkward. I'd use the second one, which is more natural. No commas are required.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are defining (restrictive) relative clauses, so you definitely shouldn't use commas.

The second sentence is a reduced relative clause, so just google 'reduced relative clause' to find out more.

However - "*I am **a** man who/that...*"is a bit unnatural - I notice that Kris changed *a* to *the*, which sounds much better. The relative clause is defining who you are - you are ***the*** man, not just any man.

Comment: You can say: "I am a man of honour" or "I am a man who has honour." Although the first sentence sounds more natural, they are both grammatical. Using "the" here would change the meaning.