# Is "induced can lead" correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, verbs

Me and my colleages have found ourselves disagreeing about the correctness of the following sentance.

"The high shear stress **induced** can lead to cell damage."

Is the word *induced* used correctly here? What is the grammar rule at play for *induced*? I do realise that this structure is a bit uncommon.

---

According to @Edwin Ashworth, this is an example of a *reduced relative clause*. Although there are other questions on reduced relative clause, none have investigated the use of *induced* specifically.

- [Is 'that is' optional?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52873/)
- [Inverted sentence/ reduced relative clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321159/)
- [In which context should I use reduced relative clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389894/)
- ["IT projects gone awry..." Qualifying a reduced relative clause rule](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181590/)

Comment: It's often seen as a _reduced relative clause_, here 'short for' _which is induced_, and non-defining.

Comment: "Induced" modifies "stress", and it's "stress" that "can lead" (pronounced "leed" and meaning "cause movement in a direction").

Comment: @Edwin can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Hot Licks In this sentance, "lead" is a synonym to "result".

Comment: *none have investigated the use of **induced** specifically.* - that is because **the general principle has been discussed**. The actual verb is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

To induce is to simply cause something to happen as a result of some "other" thing happening. For eg., from the realms of Physics we understand that "the current in the primary winding is induced by the rotating magnet".

So here,

Rotating magnet -> Causing event

Current -> Induced event

Coming to the sentence in question : If the intention was to highlight the cause of cell damage, the sentence could be framed as - "The high shear stress can induce a cell damage"

However, if the intention was also to convey that the 'high shear stress' itself was a result of some "other" event, or in other words - 'an induced high shear stress', then the sentence in question is perfectly fine, probably with a comma between 'induced' and 'can lead'.

Comment: The meaning of "induced" is mostly irrelevant, since it is modifying "stress", and that's what "can lead".

Comment: And it needs to be noted that "induced", in this usage, strongly suggests that some stress-inducing factor was described in the preceding text.